# tidalcycles + ghc: unable to load package

Tags: ghc

I'm trying to run [tidalcycles](https://tidalcycles.org/index.php/Welcome) on windows, but while booting it from atom i get the following error:

```
ghc.exe: unable to load package `network-3.0.0.0'
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: asap :: ControlPattern -> c
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: tidal :: Stream
Variable not in scope: p :: Integer -> t
Variable not in scope: p :: Integer -> t
```

I have checked and there's no conflicting versions of network or other packages, all the packages needed seem to be installed and working (i even tried to force an entire reinstall for all the dependencies) how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this is a strange problem. As implied by the version number, network-3.0.0 is newly out, perhaps there is a problem with it.

You could try installing an older version of that library:

```
ghc-pkg unregister network-3.0.0
cabal install network-2.8.0.0
```

and then reinstall tidal.

For further help you could join this live channel:
  https://talk.lurk.org/channel/tidal-install